# Paste format/style only?

Tags: macos, copy-paste, text, formatting

In Google Docs there is a nice **Paste Special > Paste Format Only** funtion; is there anything like this in Mac OS X?

If not by default, is there a way to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Format → Font → Copy Style (⌥⌘C) to copy the style of the currently highlighted text, then go to Format → Font → Paste Style (⌥⌘C) to paste the style.

[image]

Some apps change the position of this feature, such as iWork, to simply Format → Copy Style.